# Scala: value _2 is not a member of scala.concurent.Future[(String, Float)]

Tags: scala

I am writing this code using scala language in intellij-idea

```
def observeWinner(a: Future[Tuple2[String, Float]], b: Future[Tuple2[String, Float]]) = {
    if (a._2 < b._2) {
      println(s"New leader: ${b._1}, score: ${b._2}")
      b
    } else {
      a
    }
  }
```

I get the following error:

```
value _2 is not a member of scala.concurrent.Future[(String, Float)]
[error]       println(s"New leader: ${b._1}, score: ${b._2}")
```

Also symbol < and _ are not resolved

What should I do? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `val (a1, b1) = (Await.result(a, someDuration), Await.result(b, someDuration))`, and then use a1 and b1 instead of a and b. `someDuration` is of type `Duration`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work within the `Future`, returning a `Future` from your method. Like so:

```
def observeWinner(a: Future[(String, Float)], b: Future[(String, Float)])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[(String, Float)] = {
  for {
    x <- a
    y <- b
  } yield {
    if (x._2 < y._2) {
      println(s"New leader: ${y._1}, score: ${y._2}")
      y
    } else {
      x
    }
  }
}
```

Note this is the same as writing:

```
def observeWinner(a: Future[(String, Float)], b: Future[(String, Float)])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[(String, Float)] = {
  a.flatMap { x =>
    b.map { y =>
      if (x._2 < y._2) {
        println(s"New leader: ${y._1}, score: ${y._2}")
        y
      } else {
        x
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also note that you'll have to pass in an `ExecutionContext` (usually implicitly). If you're unsure about that for now, you can `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` which should take care of it. This isn't really recommended for production code, however.

Comment: Thank you alot for your reply but I still have errors

Comment: [error] C:\Users\user\Desktop\imageserver\src\main\scala\imagesearcher\BestMatchSearcher.scala:86:13: ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both lazy value global in object Implicits of type => scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
[error]  and value ec of type scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
[error]  match expected type scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
[error]     for { x <- a
[error]             ^

Comment: For the second one I get :

Comment: C:\Users\user\Desktop\imageserver\src\main\scala\imagesearcher\BestMatchSearcher.scala:87:15: ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both lazy value global in object Implicits of type => scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
[error]  and value ec of type scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
[error]  match expected type scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
[error]     a.flatMap { x =>
[error]               ^

Comment: I am new to scala and don't know how to correct it, please help me

Comment: @user10254054 Delete `(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)` from your method parameters. There are other ways to solve this but that should get you close enough.

Comment: @user10254054 I made a typo in my answer. `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` instead.

Comment: @user10254054 Cool. Accept my answer if you would be so kind :)

Comment: @user10254054 There is a gray check mark beside my answer, to the left of it. Click that and it will turn green.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, `a` it's a `Future`, and you are trying to use it as if it was a `Tuple2`. The `._2` method works only for tuples.

This is one way of doing what to want to do:

```
for { aa <- a; bb <- b } yield {
  if (aa._2 < bb._2) {
    println(s"New leader: ${bb._1}, score: ${bb._2}")
    bb
  } else {
    aa
  }
}
```

By using a for-comprehension to extract the values from the futures, you can be sure that your code will work only if both `Future`s succeeded, and will do nothing otherwise.

Comment: Thank you a lot :)